# Android: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Am getting en error while try to run the project

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/DimenRes.class
```

Here is my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



 android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.radiomango.app"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile project(':seekArc_library')
    compile project(':socialauthandroid')
    compile project(':SwipeMenuListView')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'

}
```

i tried by cleaning the project

**Build - > Clean**

after that **rebuild**, But no effect

The i **sync and clean** the project, still no result.

Finally i restart the android studio, but the issue still exciting.

Can any one please help me

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you use `compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'` may be this library are **conflicting with each other**.

Exclude part of library which is common in both of them.
Using `exclude` 
e.g.

```
compile('com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.5.4') {
  exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: I try like  compile ('com.android.support:design:24.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }    but still issue reaming there   @Dipali shah

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
```

with

```
com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0
```

You added the design library, which also makes use of the support-v4 lib. If you add both via maven-dependency, this should be handled by gradle.

Comment: after I add am getting another zip expception "duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/IntegerRes.class"  @Christopher

Comment: Then you should have an look at your dependency graph. On your terminal execute ./gradlew app:dependencies to get a list of your project dependencies. With this list you can check which libraries are using the support-v4 features.

Comment: what the path should i give in cmd for executing this command @Christopher

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
```

with

```
com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0
```

> **Apply this in gradle also add packagingOptions**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.radiomango.app"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
complie  `com.android.support:support-v13:24.0.0` //or you used  23.4.0 
compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar')
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
compile project(':seekArc_library')
compile project(':socialauthandroid')
compile project(':SwipeMenuListView')
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'//or you used compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

 }
```